# What does רבי שמעון בר נחמי do with the extra letters in the word "בזמניהם"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

On מגילה: דף ב:א there's a מחלוקת between רבי שמעון בר נחמי & רב שמן בר אבא about where in the תורה is it hinted that we read the מגילה on י"א י"ב & י"ג. I have thought of a question on רבי שמעון בר נחמי who holds we learn it out from "**כ**ימים":

The גמרא:

=======

הֵיכָא רְמִיזָא? אָמַר רַב שֶׁמֶן בַּר אַבָּא אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן, אָמַר קְרָא: ״לְקַיֵּים אֵת יְמֵי הַפּוּרִים הָאֵלֶּה **בִּזְמַנֵּיהֶם**״, זְמַנִּים הַרְבֵּה תִּקְּנוּ לָהֶם. הַאי מִיבַּעְיָא לֵיהּ לְגוּפֵיהּ! אִם כֵּן לֵימָא קְרָא ״זְמַן״, מַאי ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ — זְמַנִּים טוּבָא. וְאַכַּתִּי מִיבְּעֵי לֵיהּ: זְמַנּוֹ שֶׁל זֶה לֹא כִּזְמַנּוֹ שֶׁל זֶה! אִם כֵּן, לֵימָא קְרָא ״זְמַנָּם״, מַאי ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ — שָׁמְעַתְּ מִינַּהּ כּוּלְּהוּ. אֵימָא זְמַנִּים טוּבָא! ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ דּוּמְיָא דִּ״זְמַנָּם״: מָה ״זְמַנָּם״ תְּרֵי — אַף ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ תְּרֵי. וְאֵימָא תְּרֵיסַר וּתְלֵיסַר? כִּדְאָמַר רַב שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר יִצְחָק: שְׁלֹשָׁה עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ לְרַבּוֹיֵי, הָכָא נָמֵי: שְׁלֹשָׁה עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ לְרַבּוֹיֵי. וְאֵימָא שִׁיתְּסַר וְשִׁיבְסַר! ״וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר״ כְּתִיב. וְרַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי אָמַר, אָמַר קְרָא: ״כַּיָּמִים אֲשֶׁר נָחוּ בָהֶם הַיְּהוּדִים״. ״יָמִים״, ״כַּיָּמִים״ — לְרַבּוֹת אַחַד עָשָׂר וּשְׁנֵים עָשָׂר. וְאֵימָא תְּרֵיסַר וּתְלֵיסַר! אָמַר רַב שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר יִצְחָק: שְׁלֹשָׁה עָשָׂר זְמַן קְהִילָּה לַכֹּל הִיא, וְלָא צְרִיךְ לְרַבּוֹיֵי. וְאֵימָא שִׁיתְּסַר וְשִׁיבְסַר! ״וְלֹא יַעֲבוֹר״ כְּתִיב. רַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָנִי מַאי טַעְמָא לָא אָמַר מִ״בִּזְמַנֵּיהֶם״? ״זְמַן״ ״זְמַנָּם״ ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ לָא מַשְׁמַע לֵיהּ. וְרַב שֶׁמֶן בַּר אַבָּא מַאי טַעְמָא לָא אָמַר מִ״כַּיָּמִים״? אָמַר לָךְ: הָהוּא לְדוֹרוֹת הוּא דִּכְתִיב.

### ========================================================================
רבי שמעון בר נחמי learns out from the word "כימים", that we read the מגילה on י"א & י"ב, unlike רב שמן בר אבא, who learns it out from the word "בזמניהם".
רב שמן בר אבא uses the word "כימים" to teach that we should read on י"ד & ט"ו through every genration.
***But according to רבי שמעון בר נחמי, what does he learn out from the extra letters from the word "בזמניהם"?***

I am very eager to get answers to these questions! Please respond!!!

Comment: The Gemara clearly says he doesn’t do anything with that since he doesn’t think it’s extra. ״זְמַן״ ״זְמַנָּם״ ״זְמַנֵּיהֶם״ לָא מַשְׁמַע לֵיהּ